# Kinetic Energy in Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution

Tags: statistical-mechanics, kinetic-theory

So I was trying to arrange the expression of a Maxwell-Boltzmann velocity vector distribution into a kinetic energy distribution. Since we know that $E= \frac{1}{2} mv^2$ we can rearrange this expression to give $v^2=\frac{2E}{m}$. If we insert this expression in a Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution:
$$f(v)=\left(\frac{m}{2\pi K_BT}\right)^\frac{3}{2} \exp\left(\frac{-m(v_x^2 + v_y^2 + v_z^2)}{2K_BT}\right)$$

we get:
$$f(E)=\left(\frac{m}{2\pi K_BT}\right)^\frac{3}{2} \exp\left(\frac{-E}{K_BT}\right)$$

But Wikipedia says that the kinetic energy distribution is:
$$f(E)=2\left(\frac{E}{\pi}\right)^\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{K_BT}\right)^\frac{3}{2} \exp\left(\frac{-E}{K_BT}\right)$$
What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you followed the derivation from the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution) article?

Comment: Yes, but they derive that expression by some concepts that I never heard of like phases-space volume of momenta. I wanted to derive that expression from the normal M-B velocity distribution.

Comment: You wrote the same $f(v)$. In order to get the energy distribution $g(E)$, you must proceed from $f(v)dv=g(E)dE$.

Answer (score 6):

Kinetic energy distribution $f_E(E)$ is a function that gives probability per unit energy interval.

Since kinetic energy $E$ is a function of speed, this distribution is related to speed distribution $f_v(v)$, but its value at any energy $E$ is not merely proportional to value of $f_v(v(E))$. The derivation of $f_E(E)$ from $f_v(v)$ relies on the substitution theorem from the integral calculus.

For positive speeds $v_1,v_2$ and corresponding energies $E_1=\frac{1}{2}mv_1^2, E_2=\frac{1}{2}mv_2^2$, the probability that particle has kinetic energy in the interval $(E_1,E_2)$ is the same as the probability that it has speed in the interval $(v_1,v_2)$. We transform the expression of the second probability in the following way:

$$
P = \int_{v_1}^{v_2}f_v(v)dv => (subst. theorem) => \int_{E_1}^{E_2}f_v(v(E))v'(E) dE
$$
where

$$
v(E) = (2E/m)^{1/2}
$$
and $v'(E)$ is derivative of this function at value $E$.

The expression of the first probability is

$$
P = \int_{E_1}^{E_2}f_E(E)dE.
$$

Since we can choose $v_1,v_2$ arbitrarily close to each other, it must be

$$
f_E(E) = f_v(v(E))\frac{dv(E)}{dE}.
$$

Substituting

$$
f_v(v) = \left(\frac{m}{2\pi k_BT}\right)^{3/2} 4\pi v^2  e^{-\frac{mv^2}{2k_B T}}
$$

we obtain
$$
f_E(E) = \left(\frac{m}{2\pi k_BT}\right)^{3/2} 4\pi 2E/m \cdot e^{-\frac{E}{k_B T}} \cdot (2/m)^{1/2}\frac{1}{2}E^{-1/2}
$$

and after simplification
$$
f_E(E) = \left(\frac{1}{\pi k_BT}\right)^{3/2} 2\pi \cdot E^{1/2} e^{-\frac{E}{k_B T}}.
$$

Comment: Your answer makes total sense to me, except for the fact that I dont get how $v_1$ and $v_2$ being possibly really close implies that identity. That identity comes from a theorem in integral calculus, irregardless of the limits considered (so long as continuity is ensued in such procedure, and the substitution considered satisfies some minor requirements).

Comment: @JohannLiebert, the substitution theorem only states that the integral over $v$ has the same value as the integral over $E$, it does not state that $f_E(E)$ defined in probability theory equals $f_v(v(E))v'(E)$. Only by taking a special case $v_1-v_2 \rightarrow 0$ for which the substitution formula has to be valid too, that formula becomes obvious. This is because then the integrals can be approximately expressed as $f_E(E_1)(E_2-E_1)$ and $f_v(v(E_1))v'(E_1)(E_2-E_1)$.

Comment: I will rephrase what I meant, that the integral is equal is a well known result reviewed in Analysis courses, a good source is Rudins Principles of Analysis page 131: https://notendur.hi.is/vae11/%C3%9Eekking/principles_of_mathematical_analysis_walter_rudin.pdf

on the other hand, my point lies here: since $f_E$ and $f_v$ are **distributions** they are never related directly to physical quantities and thus it makes no sense to separate them from their role inside the respective integral representation.

Comment: I agree, $f_E,f_v$ are distributions and their use is under the integration sign. In case $f_v$ is the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution, both distributions are regular and can be expressed as functions of $E,v$. The substitution theorem states that both integrals above are the same, a corollary is that the *function* $f_E(E)$ can be expressed as $f_v(v(E))v'(E)$.

Answer (score 2):

You should think in terms of changing your integration variable.
I think you should procede this way: first of all write the integral in polar coordinates and integrate the angular variables. Then change your variable of integration from $v$ to $E=\frac12mv^2$. I actually haven't done it but it should work.
That's basically because you want to preserve the probability and to set $p(v)dv=p(E)dE$.

Comment: And as a hint: $dE=mvdv=\sqrt{2mE}dv$